# Shell script how to list file name in ascending order

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux, writing a bash script below.
The files in the current folder are stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg, and so on, I have to process files sequentially according to their names but in the below loop I get file names is some different order.

```
for i in ./*.jpg
do
filename=$(basename "$i")
echo "filename is  ./$filename"
done
```

output I get is like this

```
filename is  ./10.jpg
filename is  ./11.jpg
filename is  ./12.jpg
filename is  ./13.jpg
filename is  ./14.jpg
filename is  ./15.jpg
filename is  ./16.jpg
filename is  ./17.jpg
filename is  ./18.jpg
filename is  ./19.jpg
filename is  ./1.jpg
filename is  ./20.jpg
filename is  ./21.jpg
filename is  ./22.jpg
filename is  ./27.jpg
filename is  ./28.jpg
filename is  ./29.jpg
filename is  ./2.jpg
filename is  ./3.jpg
filename is  ./4.jpg
filename is  ./6.jpg
filename is  ./7.jpg
filename is  ./8.jpg
filename is  ./9.jpg
```

Any assistance as to how can I process them in the sequence of names 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc

Comment: Please give a us file list and the expected order. It is unclear, how to order capitals and other special characters.

Comment: @EMED : They look to me in perfect ASCII collating sequence. You could pipe the result to `sort`, which allows you to defining sorting on various criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Pathname expansion (glob expansion) returns a list of filenames which is alphabetically sorted according to your current locale. If you have something simple like `UTF-8` or `C`, your sorting order will be [ASCII sorted](http://asciitable.com/). This is visible in the result of the OP. The file with name `19.jpg` is sorted before `1.jpg` because the lt;dot>-character has a higher lexicographical order than the character `9`.

If you want to traverse your files in a different sorting order, then a different approach needs to be taken.

Under the bold assumption that the OP requests to traverse the files in a numeric sorted way, i.e. order the names according to a number at the beginning of the file-name, you can do the following:

```
while IFS= read  -r -d '' file; do 
   echo "filename: $file"
done < <(find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | sort -z -n)
```

Here we use `find` to list all files in the current directory (`depth==1`) we print them with a `\0` as a separator, and use `sort` to ask for the requested sorting, indicating that we have `\0` as the field separator. Instead of  using a for-loop, we use a while-loop to read the information.

See [BashPitFall001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) For some details

**note:** `sort -z` is a GNU extension

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but you have the echo inside your loop which will cause it to be printed in a different row each time.

you can do:

```
list "" 
for i in ./*.jpg
do
filename=$(basename "$i")
list="$list $filename"
done    
echo  "files: $list"
```

which would output

> files: 1.jpg 2.jpg

Nevertheless, You should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement to *"process them in the sequence of names 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc"*, this will accomplish that. The sort specifies a numeric key obtained by defining the first field as the string before a "." delimiter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
allfiles=(*.jpg);

for f in "${allfiles[@]}"
do
    echo "$f"
done | sort -t"." -k1n
```